# Problems with restoring the pg dump(excluding schema) in postresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I had created a backup using "pgdump --data-only" by excluding schema. Now I am trying to restore the same using "pgrestore --data-only" and I am getting the below error.

"The  relation doesn't exist".

Any ideas on how to proceed. First thing, I would like to know is, whether the "data-only pg_restore" will work in postgresql?

Comment: simple question, does the database that you are restoring to have that table already?

Comment: In general, --schema-only dumps the DDLs (table/view/function,etc definitions), and --data-only dumps the data. So restoring the data-only part *assumes* that the target DB already has the correct (empty) tables.